# Iterating over machine instructions in LLVM

Tags: iterator, llvm

Is there a way to iterate over machine instructions without using basic blocks? It is possible with plain Instructions using an instr_iterator within the context of a Function as shown here: [Iterating over the Instruction in a Function](http://llvm.org/docs/ProgrammersManual.html#iterating-over-the-instruction-in-a-function), however i didn't find a similar example with MachineFunction.

Comment: May I ask why you want to do this? What's the problem, why can't you use basic blocks?

Comment: For every 2 instructions that use the same register i want to iterate over the instructions between them and check something. The code comes out really clunky when using basic blocks.

Comment: There's a reason for that. "Between" isn't a simple concept when two instructions are in different basic blocks. LLVM provides dominator analysis; in the passes where I need to do this kind of thing, I consider "between A and B" as the set of instructions that are dominated by A and postdominated by B. This isn't the only possible definition, and it's a lot clunkier than you want, but with arbitrary jumping there's a lower limit on simplicity.

Comment: Happy fun compilering. What to do if an instruction is dominated by A, but postdominated by a return or throw instead of by B. Or if it's postdominated by the set of B and a return.

Comment: There's an order to those instructions as they are emitted in the assembly code, that's what i'm looking for. Also, the same thing can be said about IR, but it allows iteration over the instructions